# Washington accord accredited engineering degree for Australia visa subclass 476

Tags: visa, australia

I recently check the website to apply for 476 visa and I noticed they have changed the way they mentioned the name of recognized institutes and referring to them as Washington Accord institutions, however when I check the name of one institute for instance for Malaysia which is happen to be the country I did my Master's degree and I go through the list only bachelor engineering courses have been listed.

Does this mean that although my university is listed as an accredited institution, my Master's degree does not make me eligible to apply for this visa? Or does it simply mean that since the name of my institution is listed over there it is enough?

Comment: Any verification that CargoCult's answer was correct? I'm in a similar situation.

Comment: As long as your institute is recognized by Washington Accord and you have an engineering degree you are able to apply, No matter you have master's or bachelor.

Comment: My case was similar. Graduated with a MSC(1 year course) from the University of New South Wales. Wasn't sure too if I was eligible but I applied anyways. Fortunately, my 476 visa was granted on Apr 2015.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Washington Accord is only applicable to undergraduate degrees.

The 476 visa eligibility conditions, however, only specify that your degree should be from a recognised institution, including all in the Washington Accord.

Since this visa accepts the following degrees:

> - bachelors degree
> - masters degree
> - doctoral degree
> - postgraduate diploma;

and it does not explicitly link degrees to institutions, one can assume that your are eligible even if your degree is graduate degree at any recognised institution.

As with all unclear information you find in the [Department of Immigration and Border Protection DIBP](http://www.immi.gov.au) website, you can always contact the department for clarification.